# Using nodejs-imap to connect to Office365 outlook email server results in Error: NO LOGIN failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I'm building a nodejs method that will connect to an Office365 Outlook email inbox and retrieve all unread emails. It uses the nodejs-imap library to achieve this. This is my config for imap:

```
const imapConfig = {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    password: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
    host: 'outlook.office365.com',
    port: 993,
    debug: console.log,
    tls: true,
};
```

Sadly when I try connecting to the server I receive these logs and then this error message:

```
<= '* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [cgdsfDFgBvAGfsdsgQALgB....]'
=> 'A0 CAPABILITY'
<= '* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+'
<= 'A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.'
=> 'A1 LOGIN "<email>" "<password>"'
<= 'A1 NO LOGIN failed.'
Error: LOGIN failed.
```

I'm quite sure the credentials I'm using are correct, as I'm able to login my Microsoft account in a browser using them, so I'm a bit stuck on what the issue actually is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Sadly not, I did come to understand outlook no longer allows for plain authentication (uname/pword), and instead requires oauth2 to connect to the inbox. I also tried setting this up but ran into issues (which may be a result of my company's Azure setup? But unsure!), but I'd recommend following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth) guide